# Multiple rows in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have a dataset that looks roughly like this:

```
names = tibble(NAME_2=c("Location1","Location2","Location3","Location4"))
dates = tibble(date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by="days"))
types = tibble(type = c("comment","post"))
df <- merge(names,dates)
df <- merge(df, types)
zero <- seq(from=0, to=200, by=1)
df$n <- sample(zero, size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
```

Which produces a facet plot like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = n)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(type ~ NAME_2, scale = "free_y")
```

[image: Facet plot]

Is it possible to get behavior like `ncol=2` in `facet_wrap` so that Location3 and Location4 appear below Location1 and Location2? In reality I have about 12 locations, which makes it impossible to print on one page and still keep it legible.

Comment: Might be worth looking into the grid package.

Comment: Use `facet_wrap`!!!

Comment: `facet_wrap` works in one dimension, in that each facet produced is on one variable. If you want to do a x by y matrix, `facet_grid` is the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `grid.arrange`, as in:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(
  ggplot(data = df[df$NAME_2 %in% c('Location1','Location2'),], aes(x = date, y = n)) +
    geom_line() + xlab(NULL) +
    facet_grid(type ~ NAME_2, scale = "free_y"),
  ggplot(data = df[df$NAME_2 %in% c('Location3','Location4'),], aes(x = date, y = n)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(type ~ NAME_2, scale = "free_y"),
  nrow=2)
```

[image]

If you're sure that the x axis ranges line up from top to bottom, you could suppress the x axis tick marks/labels on the first plot.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly! Any idea on how to fix the y scale of one row facet? Say Location4 ranges not from 0 to 200, but 0 to 800: how can I keep the comment y-range but set the post y-range to 0 to 800 for both plots?

Comment: @Lukas I think you will have to use facet_wrap instead of facet_grid.  you can also set ylim() but that will apply to each facet I believe.