# R: pairs plot of one variable with the rest of the variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, ggpairs

I would like to generate a correlation plot with my "True" variable pairs with all of the rest (People variables). I am pretty sure this has been brought up somewhere but solutions I have found do not work for me.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)

dt = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(120, 100, 5), ncol = 6) )
colnames(dt) = c('Salary', paste0('People', 1:5))
ggplot(dt, aes(x=Salary, y=value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~Salary)
```

Where I got error: Error: Column `y` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list.

I know one of the solutions is writing out all of the variables in y - which I am trying to avoid because my true data has 15 columns.

Also I am not entirely sure what do the "value", "variables" refer to in the ggplot. I saw them a lot in demonstrating codes.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: `y = value` has no meaning as there is no `value` column in your `dt`.
Are you trying to plot salary amounts against number of people in different groups?

Comment: what I mean is would you like Salary vs. People 1 | Salary vs. Peopl2 ... and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert your data from `wide` to `long` format using `tidyr::gather()` for example. Here is a solution using packages in the `tidyverse` framework

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 14))

set.seed(0)
dt = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(120, 100, 5), ncol = 6) )
colnames(dt) = c('Salary', paste0('People', 1:5))

### convert data frame from wide to long format
dt_long <- gather(dt, key, value, -Salary)
head(dt_long)
#>      Salary     key     value
#> 1 106.31477 People1  98.87866
#> 2  98.36883 People1 101.88698
#> 3 106.64900 People1 100.66668
#> 4 106.36215 People1 104.02095
#> 5 102.07321 People1  99.71447
#> 6  92.30025 People1 102.51804

### plot
ggplot(dt_long, aes(x = Salary, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ key)
```

[image]

```r
### if you want to add regression lines
library(ggpmisc)

# define regression formula
formula1 <- y ~ x

ggplot(dt_long, aes(x = Salary, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ key) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = TRUE) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~")), 
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top",
               formula = formula1, parse = TRUE, size = 3) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

```r
### if you also want ggpairs() from the GGally package
library(GGally)
ggpairs(dt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You need to `stack()` your data first, probably that's what you have "seen".

```
dt <- setNames(stack(dt), c("value", "Salary"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(x=Salary, y=value)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~Salary)
```

***Yields***

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay, that's really helpful. I have another quick question: is it possible to display the graphs into various rows? For instance, for the graph above, only display two graphs per row, then two more the next row, then the last graph.

Comment: Yes, you could take a look into `grid.arrange` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45614824/6574038) answer.